# Android accelerometer filters

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, sensormanager

Trying to understand the official Android documentation for accelerometer sensor. It is stated [there](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html):

> It should be apparent that in order to measure the real acceleration of the device, the contribution of the force of gravity must be eliminated. This can be achieved by applying a high-pass filter. Conversely, a low-pass filter can be used to isolate the force of gravity.

And the code for the filter is:

```
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
 {
      // alpha is calculated as t / (t + dT)
      // with t, the low-pass filter's time-constant
      // and dT, the event delivery rate

      final float alpha = 0.8;

      gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
      gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
      gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

      linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
      linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
      linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
 }
```

Ok. Suppose I'm pushing the device in portrait orientation towards the sky with acceleration equal to 6 m / s^2. I think that in that case I should get something like `[0, 15, 0]` in `event.values`, right?

So, when I apply this filter for 20 points in Excel, it comes out that `gravity` tends to be equal to `[0, 15, 0]` and `linear_acceleration` aims to `[0, 0, 0]`.

What am I missing?

P.S. I know about `TYPE_GRAVITY`, just trying to understand the math.

P.P.S. Also, why `TYPE_GRAVITY` sensor returns positive `y` value (+9.806) in portrait mode? Shouldn't it be `-9.806` instead?

Comment: I actually found this statement on Android Website quite misleading. The filter they have applied in the example is a low-pass filter that filters the noise - not the gravity.

Comment: @Kasra, yeah, it does exactly that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About TYPE_GRAVITY, think about it this way:

You are sitting in box floating in space where there is no gravity. If a jet pushes you up (in +Y direction) with the acceleration of +9.8 upward. What you feel is a gravity of 9.8 downward. So technically the force that you feel due to gravity, is equivalent of a force in space where you are pushed up.

That's why you get +9.8. But again, these are just how they are "defined". there was nothing wrong if they had defined gravity -9.8. All you need to do to make all parts of your math to be following the same rule. DO NOT change the convention...

Comment: So, on every device it is positive? Or just only on mine?

Comment: The rule is yes. But, keep in mind that some devices even don't have the TYPE_GRAVITY. I "always" use accelerometer, and perform a simple filter like the one described in the example you wrote. And that's because accelerometers are always hardware based sensors. Whereas Rotation, Gravity and etc could be software based and these are not "directly" done by Android team - most are modified by the manufacturer. And there is always room for a mistake when the work is off-loaded to manufacturers...